Nate Silver's p(doom) Calculation
In his latest book, On The Edge, Nate Silver outlines a "Bayesian" calculation for the probability of nuclear war conditioned on the observation that we have not witnessed the use of nuclear arms since 1946. I'm finding his setup and solution a little vague, and I would like to follow his logic.
He writes:

How relieved should we be by the fact that nuclear weapons haven’t been used in conflict since 1945? Suppose that on January 1, 1946, you’d convened a panel of three experts to forecast the likelihood of another nuclear detonation. Peter Pessimist tells you there’s a 10 percent chance of nuclear weapons being used on an annual basis. Ollie Optimist says there’s just a 0.1 percent chance. And Mary Middleground estimates a 1 percent chance. Having no real evidence to go on, you just average their predictions together, which works out to a 3.7 percent chance per year. This is terrifying: it implies that nuclear weapons are more likely than not to be used at some point in the next twenty years. This helps to explain why people like von Neumann thought after World War II that civilization might not survive much longer. But after seventy-eight years (1946 through 2023) of nuclear weapons not being used, we can update how much weight we assign to each analyst’s estimate; this is a straightforward application of Bayes’ theorem. For instance, we can say that Peter Pessimist is probably wrong. If there really were a 10 percent annual chance of nuclear war, there’s less than a 1 in 3,000 probability that we’d have avoided one so far through luck alone. However, we don’t have enough evidence to say much about Mary Middleground’s estimate. She said there’s a 1 in 100 chance of nuclear war per year, and we only have seventy-eight years of data to refute her. (True, a good Bayesian would discount her forecast just slightly while increasing our credence to Ollie Optimist’s theory of the case.) Our revised Bayesian estimate, seventy-eight years after Nagasaki, is that there’s about a 0.35 percent chance of nuclear war per year."

He attaches a graphic that I've been trying to recreate:

I'm a little confused about Nate's steps, thought I might be overthinking it. It seems like he's updating his prior, an average over the three "experts" ((optimist 0.1% + middle ground 1.0% + pessimist 10%) / 3 = 3.7%), by weighting each expert (call them $p_1, p_2, p_3$) using observations of event outcome over the subsequent 78 years. That is, $p$(event not occurring for $n$ years | event probability) = $(1-{p_i})^n$
In an attempt to replicate this, I compute a new weighting among experts, for each $n$ from 0 to $N$=78:
\begin{align}
p'(n) &= \sum_{i=1}^3\frac{p_i(1-p_i)^n}{Z(n)} \\
Z(n) &= \sum_{i=1}^3(1-p_i)^n
\end{align}
However, this doesn't quite match Nate's plot:

Since my back of the envelope didn't work, I'm wondering if I'm off here and getting lucky, and if Nate is modeling this more elaborately? I would love to make this solution more formal and get these lines to match. Any input welcome! Thanks.

Can you add the data from Nate's chart?

Following up on my back-of-the-envelope solution with more formality, here is the discrete prior updating procedure which I believe is what Nate has done in his problem.
Our prior is a discrete distribution over the three experts, beginning with uniform weights (probability ⅓ for each expert), updating year-on-year with observations of "no nuclear war". We can organize this into a nice little table:



Hypothesis
Prior $p(H)$
Likelihood $p(D|H)$
Numerator $p(D|H)p(H)$
Posterior = Numerator/$p(D)$




$p_1$ = 0.1%
1/3
$(1-p_1)^{78} = $ 0.93
0.32
0.67


$p_2$ = 1.0%
1/3
$(1-p_2)^{78} = $ 0.46
0.15
0.33


$p_3$ = 10.0%
1/3
$(1-p_3)^{78} = $ 3e-4
9.9e-5
2e-4


Total
1

$p(D)$ = 0.46
1



If you repeat this kind of discrete prior update from year 0 to year 78, you get the plot from the question. However, it doesn't quite match Nate's values, so there's still something missing. The posterior weighted mean estimate at the 78th year is 0.40% rather than Nate's quoted 0.35%.


I see that you only have approximate values from Nate's analysis, so let me provide my own two cents.  I'm also confused about this estimate, and my own Bayesian analysis estimates P(Doom) to be higher given the same model.
The chart provided by Nate appears to be close to a negative binomial density, and the story seems to accord with that understanding (starting from 1945, what is the probability we see nuclear war in any given year).  Assuming we "sample until a success" (i.e. sample until a war, which is referred to as negative binomial sampling if I am not mistaken) given the average of the 3 forecasters, we get a density that looks like
library(tidyverse)
library(cmdstanr)

years <- 2024 - 1946

ps <- c(10, 1, 0.1)/100
p <- mean(ps)
y <- dnbinom(1:years, 1, p)
tibble(y, year = 1945 + 1:years) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(year, y)) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 0.04, 0.005), limits = c(0, 0.04)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1946, 2022, 4)) +
  theme(
    aspect.ratio = 1/1.61
  )


Assume that each year is an independent bernoulli trial.  Then, we can model the probability of nuclear war in any given year as
$$ y \sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(\theta) $$
where $\theta$ is a weighted average of all three forecasters
$$ \theta = \sum_i w_i \theta_i, \quad \sum_i w_i = 1$$
and there is a prior on the joint distribution of the weights
$$ p(w) = \operatorname{Dirichlet}(\alpha) $$
I can write a very simple Stan model to fit this data given we have not seen nuclear war in 78 years.  I'll provide a prior which provides equal weight among the 3 forecasters.  Hence, the average risk of war under the prior is approximately the same as averaging the three forecasts.  The model is sampled as follows
stan_model <- "
data{
  int years_without_war;
  int n_forecasters;
  vector[n_forecasters] probs;
}
parameters{
  simplex[n_forecasters] w;
}
model{
 w ~ dirichlet(rep_vector(1.0, n_forecasters));
 
 for(i in 1:years_without_war){
  target += bernoulli_lpmf(0| probs' * w);
 }
}
generated quantities{
  real updated_probs = probs' * w;
  vector[years_without_war] ppc;
  for(i in 1:years_without_war){
    ppc[i] = updated_probs * pow(1-updated_probs, i-1);
  }
}
"

model <- stan_model %>% 
  write_stan_file() %>% 
  cmdstan_model()

stan_data <- list(years_without_war = years, n_forecasters = length(ps), probs = ps)

fit <- model$sample(stan_data, chains = parallel::detectCores(), parallel_chains = parallel::detectCores())

> fit$summary(variables = 'w')
# A tibble: 3 × 10
  variable   mean median     sd    mad      q5   q95  rhat ess_bulk ess_tail
  <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 w[1]     0.0842 0.0595 0.0822 0.0610 0.00424 0.253  1.00    5655.    3813.
2 w[2]     0.387  0.354  0.263  0.312  0.0293  0.857  1.00    7274.    5278.
3 w[3]     0.529  0.553  0.266  0.317  0.0701  0.916  1.00    7556.    4654.

As we can see, the first forecaster's weight is extremely small.  This makes sense since were the true probability of war in a given year 10%, we would expect to see 1 war on average every 10 years.
The other two forecasters share the majority of the weight, which again makes sense.  Inference on the inferred probability of war is
> fit$summary(variables = 'updated_probs')
# A tibble: 1 × 10
  variable        mean median      sd     mad      q5    q95  rhat ess_bulk ess_tail
  <chr>          <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 updated_probs 0.0128 0.0108 0.00821 0.00645 0.00343 0.0293  1.00    7085.    5849.

So it seems that from these data, the probability of war in a given year is about 1.1% (or 1.3% depending on how you summarize the posterior).  It isn't clear to me how Nate went from 3.7% to nearly an order or magnitude smaller risk.  Perhaps my model is wrong, in which case I am willing to make changes to try to cast light on Nate's analysis.

Nice take on the problem, but I don't think either of these match Nate's plot! I added a more formal Bayesian solution as well, but still unclear exactly what Nate did here...
